# Unexpected Output from Solve with assumptions on symbolic Exponents

Tags: equation-solving

Why doesn't Mathematica output $a = b^{\frac{1}{x}}$ for the input below?

```
Solve[{a^x - b == 0, x > 0}, a, Reals]
```

Instead I get an error from Solve:

```
This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve.
```

It works if I specify $a>0$, but why is that necessary?

Thanks

Comment: The problem is that b^(1/x) is a multivalued function. And what do you think is e.g. (-1)^0.3. But you can get an answer by constraining a to be positive. E.g.: Solve[{a^x - b == 0, {a, x} > 0}, a, Reals]

Comment: Use either `Solve[{a^x - b == 0, x > 0}, a, Reals, Method -> Reduce]` or `Reduce[{a^x - b == 0, x > 0}, a, Reals]`

Comment: @DanielHuber I see, but I would expect Mathematica's symbolic approach to regard b^(1/x) as some value either in the Reals or complex plane.